# Set focus on form field and select the default text upon form load

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on an html form which employs jscript to perform functions such as loading form settings, loading the form with default values, data validation, among others. It then uses htm to display the page.

When the form loads the first field is populated with default data which is appropriate 99% of the time.  I want the first field of the form to not only acquire focus upon load but also to have the default value (text) selected so that the 1% of users can easily begin typing without having to backspace through or highlight the text.

I've looked on a number of sites including stackoverflow and the most common suggestion is to add a line -- fieldid.select();  This line would immediately follow the focus line -- fieldid.focus();  Adding the select line had no effect at all.  The field does receive focus but the cursor is blinking at the end of the default text and the text is not selected.

Here is the code snippet that I am using...

```
function windowLoad()
{
    hideExtraFields();

    loadFormSettings();

    comboEventType.focus();

    var params = getUseCaseParams();
    if (params)
    {
        inputLocation.value = params.EventLocation;
        comboEventType.value = "This is the default text";
        comboEventSubtype.value = "this is the default subtext";
    }
    else
    {
        var unitData = getMyUnitData();
        inputLocation.value = unitData.Position.LocationString;
        comboEventType.value = "This is the default text";
        comboEventSubtype.value = "this is the default subtext";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are calling select() after you have already set your default values.

```
    function windowLoad()
    {
        hideExtraFields();

        loadFormSettings();

        var params = getUseCaseParams();
        if (params)
        {
            inputLocation.value = params.EventLocation;
            comboEventType.value = "This is the default text";
            comboEventSubtype.value = "this is the default subtext";
        }
        else
        {
            var unitData = getMyUnitData();
            inputLocation.value = unitData.Position.LocationString;
            comboEventType.value = "This is the default text";
            comboEventSubtype.value = "this is the default subtext";
        }

          comboEventType.focus();
          inputLocation.focus()
          inputLocation.select()
    }
```

Order matters here. Notice this works:
http://jsfiddle.net/g1zmprmx/

But this doesn't:
http://jsfiddle.net/bspga4gb/

Comment: Your logic makes sense.  However, it didn't work when I moved the comboEventType.focus(); and comboEventType.select(); to the bottom.  The field still acquires the focus on form load but the text is not selected.  I was wondering if this might be handled better in the html code as opposed to the jscript.

Comment: I also tried placing those two lines of code in the function loadFormSettings();  again, the field still acquires focus but not select.

Comment: Can you show more code? Is comboEventType a text input? Does anything happen after windowLoad()?

Comment: When and where do you set inputLocation and comboEventType? Make sure you have the element you think you have